# Why my android emulator isn't showing buttons?

Tags: android-studio

I made this simple activity in my Android Studio. But when I run this on my Android emulator it doesn't shows the buttons that I added to my activity

`````
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="151dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="159dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="355dp"
        android:text="This is app"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="153dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="392dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="291dp"
        android:text="````
`````

Comment: remove all margins

Comment: Sorry but if I remove all the margins then how it will stay in middle of my screen?

Comment: You should really follow some guides. Please do not guess code! There are various ways of doing this. If you hardcode margins then it will NEVER look the same on every device

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="101dp"
            android:text="This is app"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click Me"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```